# How to say ViewModels in MVVM?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wpf, mvvm

The MVVM and MVC are promation models similar.
If the logic in MMVM are located in the ViewModels like Controllers in MVC.

How would you call a ViewModel in the MVVM pattern?
I mean ViewModels, like specific created entities for show data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be called the Model for the View.